# Android: Three listviews smooth animation

Tags: android, listview, animation

I really have a serious problem with animating three list views, the flow of animation is as shown in the following images
[image: Initial View]

[image: When User Press on Item, List 1 should shrink to 1/4 of its width , and list2 slide from right to left]

[image: When User Press on Item in list2, List 1 should shrink to 0, list 2 should shrink to 1/4 of its width , and list3 slide from right to left]

here is my layout file

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/categoriesList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layerType="hardware">       
</ListView>

<ListView android:id="@+id/subCategoriesList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layerType="hardware">        
</ListView>

<ListView android:id="@+id/productsList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layerType="hardware">        
</ListView>
```

and here is my code

for list1 on item click listener

```
long time = AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis();            
collapseSize = (int)(categoriesListView.getMeasuredWidth() / 4);
ObjectAnimator animator = new ObjectAnimator();
animator.setTarget(subCategoriesListView);
animator.setPropertyName("translationX");
animator.setFloatValues(3*collapseSize,0);
animator.setStartDelay(time);
animator.setDuration(1000);
animator.addUpdateListener(ShopFragment.this);
ValueAnimator.ofObject(new WidthEvaluator(categoriesListView), categoriesListView.getWidth(),collapseSize).setDuration(1000).start();
animator.start();
```

for list2 onItemClick Listener

```
ObjectAnimator animator = new ObjectAnimator();
animator.setTarget(productsListView);
animator.setPropertyName("translationX");
animator.setFloatValues(collapseSize,0);
animator.setStartDelay(time);
animator.setDuration(1000);
ValueAnimator.ofObject(new WidthEvaluator(categoriesListView),
categoriesListView.getWidth(),0).setDuration(1000).start();

ValueAnimator.ofObject(new WidthEvaluator(subCategoriesListView), subCategoriesListView.getWidth(),collapseSize).setDuration(1000).start();
animator.start();
```

and here is the Width Evaluator

```
private class WidthEvaluator extends IntEvaluator {
   private View v;
   public WidthEvaluator(View v) {
       this.v = v;
   }

   @Override
   public Integer evaluate(float fraction, Integer startValue,
            Integer endValue) {
  int num = (Integer)super.evaluate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
  ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
  params.width = num;
  v.setLayoutParams(params);
  return num;
   }                        
 }
```

User presses the back button to reverse the animation. The main issue is the animation is not smooth at all, it just jumps to the new position. Can anyone help me solve this?

Note: Those list views are inside a fragment, not an activity, if that matters. Also, I am using nineold library for backward compatibility.

Comment: What type of device are you testing this on?

Comment: You seem to be translating the view, then converting that translation into new layout width values, is that correct? Is there a reason for that? This is a bit odd since translation overrides the values from layout. Have you considered animating the width directly with a ValueAnimator and requesting a relayout each time you update the width?

Comment: @TylerAndFriends I am using samsung S3 with custom ROM [4.3]

Comment: @MattHall, I am shrinking ListView1 and translate listView2 in first case, and in second case I am shrinking list1,list2 and translate list3

Comment: @MattHall where should I use the requestLayout

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but I think it can be done much more simply with layout animations. I suggest something like the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView android:layout_width="100dp" ... />
    <ListView android:layout_width="300dp" ... />
    <ListView android:layout_width="300dp" ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

So this is a horizontal LinearLayout that contains all your ListViews. Notice the animateLayoutChanges setting in the LinearLayout. This means if you resize or add/remove view in the layout it'll animate that change for you. Now you can set the width of the first ListView, or set it to Visibility.GONE and it should animate that change for you. You can do similar things to the other ListViews as needed.